# Minimum reversals of maximal decreasing subarrays needed to sort array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, permutation

The input is a length n array, containing distinct integers from `1` to `n`.

We will perform the following algorithm. **There are no choices to be made in the algorithm**: the only goal is counting the number of reversals this algorithm will perform.

Algorithm is like below:

```
While(array not sorted in ascending order) do:
    Find all the maximal contiguous subarrays which are in decreasing order,
    and reverse each of them (simultaneously).
```

We want to find the total number of times reverse will be called in the above algorithm, in an optimal way (i.e. as efficiently as possible, so direct simulation is probably too slow).

Example 1:

```
4,3,1,2 // 1 reversal: [4, 3, 1]
1,3,4,2 // 1 reversal: [4, 2]
1,3,2,4 // 1 reversal: [3, 2]
1,2,3,4

// Reverse is called 3 times in above example
```

Example 2:

```
5 3 4 2 1 ---> 2 reversals: [5, 3], [4, 2, 1]
3 5 1 2 4 ---> 1 reversal: [5, 1]
3 1 5 2 4 ---> 2 reversals: [3, 1], [5, 2]
1 3 2 5 4 ---> 2 reversals: [3, 2], [5, 4]
1 2 3 4 5 ---> sorted

Total of 7 reversals
```

Note that `O(n^2)` reversals may be necessary to sort a sequence in this way, so a direct simulation can take that many steps to run, but there may be a way to *count* them faster than `O(n^2)`.

If `n = 2k`, then the sequence `k+1, k+2, ... , 2k, 1, 2, 3, ..., k` will require `k^2` reversals:

```
Reversals to be performed are surrounded by brackets

5, 6, 7, [8, 1], 2, 3, 4         // 1 reversal

5, 6, [7, 1], [8, 2], 3, 4       // 2 reversals

5, [6, 1], [7, 2], [8, 3], 4     // 3 reversals

[5, 1], [6, 2], [7, 3], [8, 4]   // 4 reversals

1, [5, 2], [6, 3], [7, 4], 8     // 3 reversals

1, 2, [5, 3], [6, 4], 7, 8       // 2 reversals

1, 2, 3, [5, 4], 6, 7, 8         // 1 reversal

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Total of 16 = (8/2)^2 reversals.
```

Things which I tried:

1. Trying to convert it to recursion.
2. Using stack to solve it.
3. Read about inversion but not able to solve this.
4. Read on codeforces about the thread but was not relevant to this post.

Comment: `You have to print Total number of times reverse will be called` -- no we don't; it's your homework assignment. This is not a code-writing service. See [How do I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: hey @kcsquared, you misunderstood. This is not any homework assignment. i am a professional who is currently doing job and doing competitive programming and i am looking for complexity better than O(n*n).

Comment: I don't understand the second example. A sequence `5 3 4 2 1 -> 1 2 4 3 5 -> 1 2 3 4 5` seems better.  Anything wrong with it?

Comment: It’s not about whether you’re a student or not; the issue is that the post doesn’t contain an actual question or any mention of what you’ve tried or found already, just a problem prompt. If you have an existing implementation you’re trying to optimize, it would be good to include that.

Comment: @user58697 You have to follow above algorithm given. You dont need to create your own algo

Comment: @kcsquared sure let me update

Comment: @user58697 the op has posted incomplete description, the subarray should be consecutively decreasing. i.e. after 5 3... next element should be less than 3, then only it will be considered in the same decreasing subarray.

Comment: This is a very interesting question that deserves a decent answer, but there was some confusion about the counting and the algorithm. I've edited the question to try to clarify it, adding another example and additional info. For anyone else trying to answer this, note that 1. After the first step, all reversals are done on arrays of length two or three, which implies: 2. After the first step, the [Kendall-Tau distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) (aka inversion count) is an upper bound on reversals left: there are exactly `KT-distance - 2*(length-3 reversals)` left.